# erroneous function call with case when inside UDF

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm noticing some really weird behavior when using a `CASE WHEN` statement inside a UDF in one of my queries in google bigquery. The result is really bizarre, so either I'm missing something really obvious, or there's some weird behavior in the query execution.

(side note: if there's a more efficient way to implement the query logic below I'm all ears, my query takes forever)

I'm processing some log lines, where each line contains a `data: string` and `topics: array<string>` field that are used for decoding. Each type of log line will have different length of `topics`, and requires different decoding logic. I use a `CASE WHEN` inside a UDF to switch to different methods of decoding. I originally got a strange error of indexing too far into an array. This would either mean non-conformant data, or the wrong decoder getting called at some point. I verified that all the data conformed to the spec, so it must be the latter.

I've narrowed it down to an erroneous / extraneous decoder being executed inside my `CASE WHEN` for the wrong type.

The weirdest thing is that when I go and insert fixed value instead of my decoding functions, the return value of the `CASE WHEN` doesn't indicate that it's an erroneous match. Somehow the first function is getting called when I use functions, but when debugging I get the value from the proper value from the second `WHEN`.

I pulled the logic out of the udf, and implemented it with an `if(..)` instead of `CASE WHEN` and everything decodes fine. I'm wondering what's going on here, if it's a bug in bigquery, or something weird happens when using UDFs.

Here's a stripped down version of the query

```
-- helper function to normalize different payloads into a flattened struct
create temporary function wrap_struct(payload array<struct<name string, value string>>) as (
    (select as struct
        decode_field_type1(field1) as field1,
        decode_field_type1(field2) as field2,
        decode_field_type2(field3) as field3,
        -- a bunch more fields
    from (select * from 
        (select p.name, p.value 
            from unnest(payload) as p) pivot(string_agg(value) for name in (
                'field1', 'field2', 'field3', --a bunch more fields
            )
        )
    ))
);

-- this topic uses the data and topics in the decoding, and has a topics array of length 4
-- this gets called from the switch with a payload from topics2, which has a shorter topics array of length 1, causing a failure
create temporary function decode_topic1(data string, topics array<string>) as
(
    wrap_struct([
        struct("field1" as name, substring(topics[offset(1)], 3) as value),
        struct("field2" as name, substring(topics[offset(2)], 3) as value),
        struct("field3" as name, substring(topics[offset(3)], 3) as value),
        struct("field4" as name, substring(data, 3, 64) as value)
    ])
);

--this uses only the data_payload, and has a topics array of length 1
create temporary function decode_topic2(data string, topics array<string>) as
(
    wrap_struct([
        struct("field1" as name, substring(data, 3, 64) as value),
        struct("field5" as name, substring(data, 67, 64) as value),
        struct("field6" as name, substring(data, 131, 64) as value)
    ])
);

create temporary function decode_event_data(data string, topics array<string>) as 
(
    -- first element of topics denotes the type of event
    case
        -- somehow the function decode_topic1 gets called when topics[0] == topic2
        -- HOWEVER, when i replaced the functions with a fixed value to debug
        -- i get the expected results, indicating a proper match.
        -- this is not unique these topics
        -- it happens with other combinations also.
        when topics[offset(0)] = 'topic1' then decode_topic1(data, topics)
        when topics[offset(0)] = 'topic2' then decode_topic2(data, topics)
        -- a bunch more topics
        else wrap_struct([])
    end
);

select
    id, data, topics,
    decode_event_data(data, topics) as decoded_payload
from (select * from mytable
where 
    topics[offset(0)] = 'topic1'
    or topics[offset(0)] = 'topic2'
```

when i change the base query to:

```
select
    id, data, topics, decode_topic2(data, topics)
from (select * from mytable
where 
topics[offset(0)] = 'topic2'
```

it decodes fine.

What's up with the `CASE WHEN`?

edit: Here's a query on a public dataset that can generate the problem:

```
    concat('0x', substring(raw, 25, 40))
);

create temporary function decode_amount(raw string) as (
    concat('0x', raw)
);

create temporary function wrap_struct(payload array<struct<name string, value string>>) as (
    (select as struct
        decode_address(sender) as reserve,
        decode_address(`to`) as `to`,
        decode_amount(amount1) as amount1,
        decode_amount(amount2) as amount2,
    from (select * from 
        (select p.name, p.value 
            from unnest(payload) as p) pivot(string_agg(value) for name in (
                'sender', 'to', 'amount1', 'amount2'
            )
        )
    ))
);

create temporary function decode_mint(data_payload string, topics array<string>) as
(
    wrap_struct([
        struct("sender" as name, substring(topics[offset(1)], 3) as value),
        struct("amount1" as name, substring(data_payload, 3, 64) as value),
        struct("amount2" as name, substring(data_payload, 67, 64) as value)
    ])
);

create temporary function decode_burn(data_payload string, topics array<string>) as
(
    wrap_struct([
        struct("sender" as name, substring(topics[offset(1)], 3) as value),
        struct("amount1" as name, substring(data_payload, 3, 64) as value),
        struct("amount2" as name, substring(data_payload, 67, 64) as value),
        struct("to" as name, substring(topics[offset(2)], 67, 64) as value)
    ])
); 

select
    *,
    case
        when topics[offset(0)] = '0x4c209b5fc8ad50758f13e2e1088ba56a560dff690a1c6fef26394f4c03821c4f' then decode_mint(data, topics)
        when topics[offset(0)] = '0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822' then decode_burn(data, topics)
    end as decoded_payload
from `public-data-finance.crypto_ethereum_kovan.logs` 
where
    array_length(topics) > 0
    and (
        (array_length(topics) = 2 and topics[offset(0)] = '0x4c209b5fc8ad50758f13e2e1088ba56a560dff690a1c6fef26394f4c03821c4f')
        or (array_length(topics) = 3 and topics[offset(0)] = '0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822')
    )
```

Comment: I was not able to replicate the issue on testing data. I used the same level of nesting temporary functions, so this seems to be something with related with the data. Can you provide some example data that is generating the issue?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I edited my initial post to include a query on a public dataset that can reproduce the issue (at the bottom of the post).

Comment: The code is not whole it seems... I tried to fix `decode_address` function but it's not run properly showing `Array index 2 is out of bounds (overflow)`...

Comment: Yeh I cut down my query quite a bit as to not have details of my business logic in there.

Comment: This array problem is the one I was posting about. Something strange goes on with how UDFs get executed with the case statements. Maybe all get executed, but it only picks the execution matching the WHEN. The where clause should guarantee we never have a topic length that mismatches what the decoder expects.

Anyway, i now run multiple jobs, 1 for each topic line and it works fine. When I try to run all the topics at once, I get the array out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The `offset(nn)` is killing your function, change it for safe_offset(nn) and it will solve the problem. Also, this `to` field is generally empty in `decode_burn`, or null when `decode_mint`, so, at least with this data its just causing problem.

The following works and solve this issue:

```sql
create temporary function decode_burn(data_payload string, topics array<string>) as
(
    wrap_struct([
        struct("sender" as name, substring(topics[offset(1)], 3) as value),
        struct("amount1" as name, substring(data_payload, 3, 64) as value),
        struct("amount2" as name, substring(data_payload, 67, 64) as value),
        struct("to" as name, substring(topics[SAFE_OFFSET(2)], 67, 64) as value)
    ])
);
```

[image]

---

#### Edit1:

I have analyzed in detail the data sent to the functions and steps and you a right about the filters and how it is working. Seams you have reached a specific corner case *(or bug ?)*:

As far as a could understand by the processing steps, BQ is optimizing your functions, as they are very similar, except by the fact that there is an additional field in one of them.

So, BQ engine is using the same optimized function for both data, which is causing the exception when the input is the data of rows with `topics[OFFSET(0)] = '0x4c209b5fc8ad50758f13e2e1088ba56a560dff690a1c6fef26394f4c03821c4f'`

As this is happening:

- using the `safe_offset` still a good call;
- Or, Create only one function and use the conditional on it, in this case the query will be processed correctly:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION decode(data_payload string, topics ARRAY<string>) AS ( 
  wrap_struct([ 
    STRUCT("sender" AS name,
    SUBSTRING(topics[OFFSET(1)], 3) AS value),
    struct("amount1" as name, substring(data_payload, 3, 64) as value),
    struct("amount2" as name, substring(data_payload, 67, 64) as value),
    if(topics[OFFSET(0)] = '0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822',
        STRUCT("to" AS name, topics[OFFSET(2)] AS value),null )])
      
);

select *, decode(DATA,topics) ...
```

- In parallel, you can open a case on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)

Comment: I fixed it a while ago by changing for 1 mono-job to many smaller jobs, each dealing with one of the cases. I'll see if this works.

Comment: I'm curious as to why there works. Could you elaborate a little on offset vs. safe_offset?

I don't understand how the offset ever gets called with an out-of-bounds offset given the conditions I put it at the base query?

Comment: Some data being sent to the function offsef in the possition (2) is out of range, A troubleshooting you show you that. The function safe_offset will do the same thing as the function offset, but in case of accessing out of range, it will return an empty value instead of an error. [Here is the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#:~:text=SAFE_OFFSET%3A%20The%20index%20starts%20at%20zero.%20Returns%20NULL%20if%20the%20index%20is%20out%20of%20range.) reference

Comment: The condition I put in are: 
```(array_length(topics) = 2 and topics[offset(0)] = '0x4c209b5fc8ad50758f13e2e1088ba56a560dff690a1c6fef26394f4c03821c4f')```or ```(array_length(topics) = 3 and topics[offset(0)] = '0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822')```

I don't understand how we get into the function that decode the latter with a short topics array. Any topics that matches the condition to go to the decoder should also have the correct amount of topics.

Comment: Hi @sprw121, You are right about this, it should not be happening. I have added more information in my response about the last analysis I did. I hope it help you on the understanding.